# Python subprocess.run different behavior vs Windows cmd prompt when using adb

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

I am trying to understand why I get an error when running adb through cmd prompt in Windows, but don't get it in subprocess.run.

Here is what I am doing. I am running adb -s without providing it a serial number or device id. This causes adb to throw an error in cmd:

```
c:\platform-tools>adb -s shell ls
adb.exe: ls requires an argument

c:\platform-tools>adb -s
adb.exe: -s requires an argument
```

However, if I use subprocess.run with shell=False:

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\platform-tools\\adb.exe', '-s', '', 'shell', 
 ls'],capture_output=True)
```

I get no errors and it executes the the shell command ls.

If I run it without a shell command and just '-s ' it simply executes as if I just ran adb.exe on it's own and lists the help text

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\platform-tools\\adb.exe', '-s',''],capture_output=True)
```

What exactly is going on with subproccess.run that it knows to ignore empty arguments?

Update:
I am just curious regarding this difference because I am writing a small helper script to let the user choose whether or not to enter a serial number if they have multiple devices attached otherwise it defaults to `''`. I noticed subprocess.run seem to ignore the empty arguments so I can get away without having a conditional statement to include/exclude the "-s" option and just always keep the "-s" option there.

Comment: Why are you passing an empty argument to `-s`? That is then not at all identical to your CMD usage.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, `adb -s shell ls` passes `shell` as the argument to `-s`.

Comment: Quoting on Windows is arcane but try `adb -s "" shell ls`

Comment: (Do you _have_ to pass `-s` though? Options are generally, uh, optional.)

Comment: Will try the `adb -s "" shell ls` cmd in lab when I got back in the office.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `adb` with a serial number (`-s`) equals to `shell` and then `ls` complains of a missing argument

```
adb -s shell ls
```

It is exactly the same as

```
adb ls
adb: ls requires an argument
```

with the difference that the former will later complain again that the device with serial number `shell` does not exist.

If you are not specifying a real serial number then don't use `-s`.